# How to graph with geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three tables:

```
Upper  Bound  
    Q      C   
    1     30  
    2     50  
    3     40

Lower  Bound      
    Q      C       
    1     10   
    2     15     
    3     20
```

Bad Data:

```
Q      C      Name  
1      50     Sample 1  
2      40     Sample 1  
3      30     Sample 1  
1      0      Sample 2  
2      60     Sample 2  
3      5      Sample 2
```

I want a graph that graphs the lower and upper bounds in gray and fills everything  in between and graph the bad samples on top with different colors and a legend:

```
plot <- ggplot(Bad_Data, aes(x = Bad_Data$Q, y = Bad_Data$C, group = 1))
plot + geom_line(aes(color = N)) + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = Lower_Bound$C, ymax = Upper_Bound$C))
```

I tried that but it gave me this error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (624): ymin, ymax, x, y, group

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: You don't need the `Bad_Data$` part inside the `aes`.

Comment: Put all your data in one data frame with columns Q, C, Name, Upper and Lower. Don't use `data$column` inside `aes()`, just use the unquoted column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a start, you can tweak the colors and other parameters to get the dynamics exactly as you like. I have added a few aesthetics with description of what each does:

```
#Prepare
Bad_Data$Lower_Bound <- Lower_Bound$C
Bad_Data$Upper_Bound <- Upper_Bound$C

#Plot
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(Bad_Data, aes(x = Q, y = C, color=Name, group=Name))
p <- p + geom_line()
p + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=Lower_Bound, ymax=Upper_Bound), 
                alpha=0.1,       #transparency
                linetype=1,      #solid, dashed or other line types
                colour="grey70", #border line color
                size=1,          #border line size
                fill="green")    #fill color
```

[image]
**Data**

Here is the data:

```
Upper_Bound <- read.table(text="Q      C   
1     30  
                          2     50  
                          3     40", header=T)

Lower_Bound <- read.table(text="Q      C       
                          1     10   
                          2     15     
                          3     20", header=T) 

Bad_Data <- read.table(text="Q      C      Name  
                       1      50     Sample1  
                       2      40     Sample1  
                       3      30     Sample1  
                       1      0      Sample2  
                       2      60     Sample2  
                       3      5      Sample2", header=T)
```

**Edit**

Safer preparation:

```
Bad_Data$Lower_Bound <- Lower_Bound$C[match(Bad_Data$Q, Lower_Bound$Q)]
Bad_Data$Upper_Bound <- Upper_Bound$C[match(Bad_Data$Q, Upper_Bound$Q)]
```

Comment: gives me this error      
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (624): ymin, ymax, x, y, colour, group

Comment: I posted data on the bottom. Did you use that example? Or did you use your real data?

Comment: I have posted the data that I used and the output to show that it in fact works. If this does not work on your actual data, at least you know that it is possible and how it works.

Comment: yeah i used my data and it had different names so i screwed up it worked thanks so much ur are the very best best XD

Comment: it worked 5 sec ago -.- 
now its giving me this error
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Upper_Bound", value = c(389921, 96857,  : 
  replacement has 39 rows, data has 1013

Comment: We were cheating in our assignment. Our Bounds data frames had three rows each, and our actual data had 6. Since 6 is a multiple of 3, R recycled the three rows to fill out the data frame. In this case, your replacement is not a perfect multiple. I had a feeling this would happen. I can add an extra buffer to cover these cases

Comment: I added a safer assignment.

Comment: its not graphing now .-.

Comment: You have to give me more than "It's not graphing". Please add more data to the question with the specific errors that you receive.

Comment: i screwed up never mind can u help me with this problem though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38648198/how-to-do-a-ggplot-that-graphs-50-names-per-graph-and-saves-all-of-the-graphs-in

Answer (score 6):

I use `geom_ribbon` to shade forecast confidence intervals with forecasts. You can combine several data frames to make it all work. You need to pass the data frame, x values (dates) and y values (two lines to shade between).

The following function is used for plotting a series, the model backtest, predictions and confidence intervals.

```
plot_predictions <- function(start_date) {
    # function to use Plotly to plot the predictions,
    # confidence interval and actuals
    # inputs:
    # plot_df, starting date of the series, r-pred (prediction data frame)

# output: interactive plot of the actual and the model backtest

# set the end date parameter first
pred_end <- as.Date(tail(r_pred$week_ending, 1))


p <- ggplot() + 
# add the backtest series from the backtest data frame
geom_line(data=r_back, mapping = aes(x=week_ending, y=Backtest_Model,
                                   color = 'Backtest Model'), linetype='solid') + 

# add the actual series from the training dataframe
# use aes_string to pass the series variable
geom_line(data=r_train, mapping = aes_string(x='week_ending', y=series,
                                   color = 'series'), linetype='solid') +

# r_pred holds he predictions and confidence levels
geom_line(data=r_pred, mapping = aes(x=week_ending, y=Predictions,
                                   color = 'Predictions'), linetype='solid') + 


# upper forecast limit
geom_line(data=r_pred, mapping = aes(x=week_ending, y=upper_conf_limit,
                                   color = 'upper_limit'), linetype='solid') + 

# lower forecast limit
geom_line(data=r_pred, mapping = aes(x=week_ending, y=lower_conf_limit,
                                   color = 'lower_limit'), linetype='solid') + 


# format the plot 
scale_linetype_manual() + 

# prediction_pal is a five color palette
scale_color_manual(values = pred_pal, name = "Series") +

# fill between lines with geom_ribbon using a blue toned down by alpha
geom_ribbon(data=r_pred, aes(x = week_ending, 
                             ymin=lower_conf_limit,
                             ymax=upper_conf_limit),
            fill="blue", alpha=0.2) + 



# format the y axis with commas
scale_y_continuous(label = comma)

# extend the date series from the beginning to end of predictions
scale_x_date(breaks = pretty_breaks(20),
             limits = c(as.Date(start_date), pred_end)) +  


# add the custom theme    
theme_bryan() + 

# customize the plot
# rotate the text of the x axis
theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle= 45, hjust = 1)) + 
labs(fill = 'Series') + 
guides(color = guide_legend(reverse = FALSE)) +


# add the holiday lines as vertical red dotted lines
# holidays in the training set
geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(holiday$week_ending),
           linetype='dotted', colour = 'red', alpha =0.5) + 

# holidays in the forecasting set
    geom_vline(xintercept = as.numeric(r_exog_lines$week_ending),
               linetype='dotted', colour = 'red', alpha =0.5)

# output the plot in Plotly format
subplot(with_options(list(digits = 0),
                     ggplotly(p))) %>% 
    layout(legend = list(orientation = 'v', y = .1, x = 0))
}
```

Using a series called riders `series <- 'riders'` yields the following.

[image]