# how to organize a datagram in R by a column

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that look like this:

```
Quality     Data     Name  
  1          667     white  
  2          647     white   
  3          626     white  
  1          345     Blue  
  2          550     Blue 
  3          730     Blue 
  1          500     red  
  2                  red 
  3          123     red
```

How can i make it merge in a way that its the same as quality :

```
Quality     Data     Name      Data    Name    Data    Name
  1          667     white     345     Blue    500     red 
  2          647     white     550     Blue    NULL    red
  3          626     white     730     Blue    123     red
```

Comment: You are aware that repeating column names leads to extraction ambiguity? If that is okay, then try this expression where `df1` is the name of the dataset `setNames(do.call("cbind", c(list(unique(df1$Quality)), split(df1[-1], df1$Name))),c(names(df1)[1],rep(names(df1)[-1], length(unique(df1$Name)))))`

Comment: I am trying to do this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38470111/how-to-graph-with-geom-ribbon  
but no one can answer that one so jam trying to find a way to do it

Comment: I wish you would've have linked to your previous question from the start. This work will not get to your solution. We have now created one data frame, but the structure has been ruined. We have colors in multiple columns, values in multiple columns.

Comment: How can i do it then ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. But you must know that `ggplot` is designed for tidy data. That's what you have already with the data frame above. All the colors are in one column, The values are in one column, and the groups are in one column. Don't change that. Is there a picture of the type of graph you are looking for?

Comment: https://postimg.org/image/ldhoq6wvl/     where the grey area is the upper and lower bounds and the bad sample in different colors ik how to graph all of them but i want the upper and lower bound grey

Comment: I posted an answer on your other question. You can change the colors and the rest of it to specify.

Answer (score 1):

We can separate this for more explanation, but the heart of the expression is `split(df1[-1], df1$Name)`. This splits the data by the `Name` column. The rest is for looks:

```
setNames(do.call("cbind", c(list(unique(df1$Quality)), (s<-split(df1[-1], df1$Name))[match(unique(df1$Name),names(s))])),c(names(df1)[1],rep(names(df1)[-1], length(unique(df1$Name)))))
#  Quality Data Name Data Name Data  Name
#4       1  345 Blue  500  red  667 white
#5       2  550 Blue NULL  red  647 white
#6       3  730 Blue  123  red  626 white
```